# Why is my Express api register route not POSTing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a small authentication system for a practice project I have. I am trying to send POST requests via postman to my express server(http://localhost:4000/api/register), and it's replying back "404 not found" I am following the tutorial [here](http://blog.slatepeak.com/refactoring-a-basic-authenticated-api-with-node-express-and-mongo/).

Here is my server.js:

```
const newpost = require('./routes/newpost');
const getposts = require('./routes/getposts');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const deleteposts = require('./routes/delete');
const editposts = require('./routes/editposts');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config');
const webpackMiddleware = require('webpack-dev-middleware');
const webpackHotMiddleware = require('webpack-hot-middleware');
const passport = require('passport');

const port = 4000;
const compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);
const config = require('./config/main');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const authRouter = require('./routes/authrouter');
const logger = require('morgan');


// db connection
mongoose.connect(config.database);

app.use(passport.initialize());
/*

app.use(webpackMiddleware(compiler, {
  noInfo: true, publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  log: console.log,
}));

*/
app.use(cors());
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(logger('dev'));


app.use('/newpost', newpost);
app.use('/posts', getposts);
app.use('/delete', deleteposts);
app.use('/edit', editposts);
//auth router to handle auth routes 
authRouter(app);


/*
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/index.html'));
}); */

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

Here is my authrouter.js. These are the routes I'm exporting into my server.js.  :

```
const AuthenticationController = require('../controllers/authentication');
const express = require('express');
// const passportService = require('../config/passport');
/* eslint-disable */

const passport = require('passport');

// Middleware to require login/auth
// const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });
const requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });


module.exports = function(app){
  "use-strict";
  // init route groups
  const apiRoutes = express.Router();
  const authRoutes = express.Router();

  // auth routes
  // set auth routes as subgroup/middleware to apiRoutes
  apiRoutes.use('/auth', authRoutes);

  // Registration routes
  authRoutes.post('/register', AuthenticationController.register);

  // Login route
  authRoutes.post('/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);

  // Set url for API group routes
  app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
};
```

Here is my authentication.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
// const crypto = require('crypto'); used for pw resets
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/main');

function generateToken(user) {
  return jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {
    expiresIn: 10080, // in seconds
  });
}

// set user info from request
function setUserInfo(request) {
  return {
    _id: request._id,
    email: request.email,
    role: request.role,
  };
}

// Login Route
exports.login = function (req, res, next) {
  const userInfo = setUserInfo(req.user);

  res.status(200).json({
    token: `JWT${generateToken(userInfo)}`,
    user: userinfo,
  });
};

// registration route
exports.register = function (req, res, next) {
// check for registration errors

  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  // Return error if no email provided
  if (!email) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter an email address' });
  }

  // Return error if no pw provided
  if (!password) {
    return res.status(422).send({ error: 'You must enter a password' });
  }

  User.findOne({ email }, (err, existingUser) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }

    // if user is not unique, return error
    if (existingUser) {
      return res.status(422).send({ error: 'That email address is already in use' });
    }

    // if email is unique and pw was provided, create acct
    const user = new User({
      email,
      password,
    });

    user.save((err, user) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }

      // Subscribe member to Mailchimp list
      // mailchimp.subscribeToNewsLetter(user.email);
      // Respond with JWT if user was created

      const userInfo = setUserInfo(user);

      res.status(201).json({
        token: `JWT ${generateToken(userInfo)}`,
        user: userInfo,
      });
    });
  });
};

// Role authorization check
exports.roleAuthorization = function (role) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    const user = req.user;

    User.findById(user._id, (err, foundUser) => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(422).json({ error: 'No user was found' });
        return next(err);
      }

      // if user is found, check role
      if (foundUser.role == role) {
        return next();
      }

      res.status(401).json({ error: 'You are not authorized to view this content ' });
      return next('Unauthorized');
    });
  };
};
```

Here is my passport.js :

```
// Importing Passport; strategies; and config
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('./main');
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

const localOptions = { usernameField: 'email' };

// setting up the local Strategy
const localLogin = new LocalStrategy(localOptions, ((email, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { error: 'Your login details could not be verified. Please try again.',
      });
    }
    user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!isMatch) {
        return done(null, false, { error: 'Your login details could not be verified. Please try again.',
        });
      }

      return done(null, user);
    });
  });
}));

const jwtOptions = {
  // Telling passport to check auth headers for JWT
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
  // Telling passport where to find the secret
  secretOrKey: config.secret,
};

// setting up JWT login strategy
const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, ((payload, done) => {
  User.findById(payload._id, (err, user) => {
    if (err) { return done(err, false); }

    if (user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false);
    }
  });
}));
// allow passport to use the strategies we defined
passport.use(jwtLogin);
passport.use(localLogin);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the correct post endpoint would be api/auth/register